# Magento2 custom layout unable to access custom module phtml file for products

Tags: php, module, customization, magento2.2

For my **Magento2** website I have created a `custom module and layout for products`. I have assigned that custom layout for that product from product edit design section. And from that layout, we are calling the particular module phtml files. This functionality works on localhost as well as staging website but on Live website this functionality not work. On frontend product loaded the default 1 column layout.

> New Layout.xml code path : vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/page_layout/

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="empty"/>
    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
        <container name="header.container" as="header_container" label="Page Header Container" htmlTag="header" htmlClass="page-header" before="main.content"/>
        <container name="page.top" as="page_top" label="After Page Header" after="header.container"/>
        <container name="some.container" as="someContainer" label="Some Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="some-container" />
        <referenceContainer name="some.container">
            <block class="Configurator\ProductBedz\Block\Display" name="produtctsbedz_display" template="Configurator_ProductBedz::jsonconfigurator.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>

        <container name="footer-container" as="footer" before="before.body.end" label="Page Footer Container" htmlTag="footer" htmlClass="page-footer"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</layout>
```

Can anyone let me know what is the issue and how to solve this issue on live website. The same code is working on my localhost and staging website.

Comment: have you renegerated all static content? Have all extension in live same in local?

Comment: Yes I have generated the static contents many times. Also having the same extension in live as well as local.

Comment: @Jinesh even I have put my layout code in product design " Layout Update XML" fields also. but no change.

Comment: in live and local have same extension?

Comment: @Jinesh yes same extension on local and live

Comment: @Jinesh we have found the issue its related to the custom pagination files which we have created for this module. But the same file working on local onlive it gives error `[2019-10-15 06:52:46] main.CRITICAL: Invalid block type: Magento\Theme\Block\Html\PagerCustom [] []`

Comment: Okay that's good